# Custom Payment IPN notify_url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

On my website I'm using a custom PayPal checkout form and one of the elements in the form is:

```
input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.example.com/ipn.php"
```

On actual PayPal I have my real ipn link, but could I route this to another ipn?

For example, let's say under my PayPal settings my ipn is: `http://www.example.com/ipn_1.php`
Can I set this link to say: `http://www.example.com/ipn_2.php` and then receive payment notifications at `ipn_2.php` instead of `ipn_1.php` like it says in my merchant settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you use notify_url that will override what you have in your PayPal profile so it would hit that IPN URL instead.

Comment: I guess I should add that it's only usually the case.  Subscription and Recurring Payments will always fall to your profile setting, but with everything else you can override using notify.

Comment: Just got back on here and noticed this comment. Are you saying I I set up a new recurring payment for a user and it's using "notif_url" to use a different ipn script than my profile is set to, this ipn url will be ignored and on the second payment the user's request will be sent to my default ipn as defined in my merchant settings?

Comment: That is correct, and actually, I don't think the original IPN would go to the notify_url either.  I'm pretty sure all transactions involving recurring payments use your account profile setting.

Comment: Okay, I'll just have to recode the ipn to handle two-sites i suppose because they both use recurring payments. Thank you.